# Pick out the true statement(s)

Tags: real-analysis

Pick out the true statement(s).

(a) If $f :(−1, 1)\to\Bbb R$ is bounded and continuous, it is uniformly continuous.

(b) If $f : S^1\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous.

(c) If $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq X$, then the function $f(x) = d(x,A)$ defined by $$d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x, y) : y \in A\}$$ is uniformly continuous.

i think a is false as domain is not closed and b is true as domain is closed and bounded. no idea about c

Comment: For (a), if it is false (which it is) one should produce an **example**. Hint: Lots of wiggle.

Comment: You really should start learning how to use MathJax and format your posts clearly; there are lots of links and suggestions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(c) is true. Just think about what $x \mapsto d(x, A)$ means geometrically. Moving $x$ by $k$ units cannot change $d(x, A)$ by more than $k$ units.